# Is it possible to record only part of a screen?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mediarecorder

I want to record only part of a screen

I`ve tried [this sdk](https://github.com/HBiSoft/HBRecorder) to record a screen, but I was able to record only full screen of device

Answer (score 0):

Screen recording can be done without requiring root (Android 5+) using the [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html) package. An example of a recording activity can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/bf1e262/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java).